# Strange Progress Bar Behavior offsetwidth

Tags: javascript, offsetwidth

I started developing a simple progress bar using vanilla JavaScript. As far as grabbing a width set in CSS the only way I found with JS is to use `.offsetWidth` - The following is the code for the functionality demo I was beginning to setup. The fiddle link is at the bottom of the question.

HTML:

```
<section id="box"></section>
<p>
<section id="box2"></section>
```

CSS:

```
#box, #box2 {
height: 10px;
width: 5px;
background-color: lightBlue;
}
#box2 {
width: 4px;
}
```

JavaScript (onload) :

```
var savedwidth = document.getElementById("box").offsetWidth;
alert("box 1 width " + savedwidth);
savedwidth = document.getElementById("box2").offsetWidth;
alert("box 2 width " + savedwidth);
```

While testing it out to see if it grabbed the property accurately I noticed that when the width was set to `5px` it returned `6px`. Everything else seems fine. 
4px = 4px, 6px = 6px.

I was curious if anyone knew why that happened? It's minimal enough where it won't affect what I'm trying to do seemingly, but the more you know the better off you'll be.

FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/5yk9e5du/

Comment: Seems to be working on jsfiddle

Comment: JSFiddle works in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Thanks for viewing guys! So it's returning 5 for the first box then? I'm using Chrome and I still get 6.

Comment: Yeah, in Chrome for me I'm getting box 1 5 and box 2 4  http://prntscr.com/7atjie

Comment: Fine here as well, you can give them padding and border 0 or check whether the browser adds any default values.

Comment: @Samurai That is so weird. I still get this: http://prntscr.com/7atl7f  - but I'm surprised I'm the only one.